# not possible to pass a float to another function?

Tags: c, function, floating-point

I want to pass a float number to another function.

```
int main()
{

float start=0;
float step=0.1;
int number=10;

fun(start,step,number)


}

fun(float star, float ste, int numbe)
{

//here I get "star = 0", "numbe = 10", but "ste = -1.084264e-19" 

}
```

what is wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: You have to define or declare the function before you call it.

Comment: What is wrong here? What is wrong is that you do not tell us what goes wrong. It's your program? What happens when you compile it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is most certainly possible to pass a `float` to a function, as long as you provide a prototype or move the definition ahead of the first use of the function.

A prototype (also called a forward declaration) looks like this:

```
void fun(float star, float ste, int number);
```

In larger projects, prototypes go into header files.

Note: do not forget to add `void` in front of the function definition as well. Otherwise, the compiler treats your function as returning an `int`.

If you omit the prototype, the compiler will default to using the old K&R C rules to decide how to pass arguments to your function.  The result is the unusual behaviour you are seeing, and *hopefully* a compiler warning as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need a correct function declaration before your function call:

Add:

```
 void fun(float star, float ste, int numbe);
```

before your `main` declaration and also add `void` return type in your `fun` function definition.

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare the function before `main` function. 
Try this:

```
void fun(float star, float ste, int number);

int main()
{    
  float start=0;
  float step=0.1;
  int number=10;

  fun(start,step,number);
}
```